# How to make a column go to the next line when it is overflowing the width of the div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a menu that is overflowing its container. How can I get the overflowing part to start on a new line and stay in the parent element?

[Example](https://codepen.io/twan-stins/pen/BayzXgq)

This is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="product-menu" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="kolom">
        <h2>Woonkamer</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="woonkamer/gordijnen">Gordijnen</a></li>
            <li><a href="woonkamer/zitzak">Zitzak</a></li>
            <li><a href="woonkamer/bootstickers">Bootstickers</a></li>
            <li><a href="woonkamer/plafondoek">Plafondoek</a></li>
            <li><a href="woonkamer/spanplafond">Spanplafond</a></li>
            <li><a href="woonkamer/vloer-pvc">Vloer PVC</a></li>
            <li><a href="woonkamer/tapijt">Tapijt</a></li>
            <li><a href="woonkamer/schoonloopmat">Schoonloopmat</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="kolom">
        <h2>Tuin</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="tuin/zitzak">Zitzak</a></li>
            <li><a href="tuin/bbq-schort">BBQ schort</a></li>
            <li><a href="tuin/outdoor-poster">Outdoor poster</a></li>
            <li><a href="tuin/schuttingframe">Schuttingframe</a></li>
            <li><a href="tuin/schuttingdoek">Schuttingdoek</a></li>
            <li><a href="tuin/rode-loper">Rode loper</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="kolom">
        <h2>Slaapkamer</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="slaapkamer/bootstickers">Bootstickers</a></li>
            <li><a href="slaapkamer/dekbedovertrek">Dekbedovertrek</a></li>
            <li><a href="slaapkamer/sierkussens">Sierkussens</a></li>
            <li><a href="slaapkamer/spanplafond">Spanplafond</a></li>
            <li><a href="slaapkamer/acoustische-panelen">Acoustische panelen</a></li>
            <li><a href="slaapkamer/vol-karton-2mm">Vol karton 2mm</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="kolom">
        <h2>Keuken</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="keuken/acrylaat">Acrylaat</a></li>
            <li><a href="keuken/theedoek">Theedoek</a></li>
            <li><a href="keuken/tafelkleed">Tafelkleed</a></li>
            <li><a href="keuken/achterwand">Achterwand (spatwand)</a></li>
            <li><a href="keuken/placemats">Placemats</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="kolom">
        <h2>Kantoor</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="kantoor/schoonloopmat">Schoonloopmat</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use display flex to align the colomns from left to right but it won't go to a new line when overflowing the parent div (`product-menu`).

How can I fix it?

Comment: <div class="product-menu" style="display: flex; **flex-wrap: wrap;**">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, CSS flexbox won't allow items to wrap to the next line.
But you can choose to allow flex items to wrap by using CSS `flex-wrap: wrap;` on the flexbox container.

You could replace the first line in your HTML with:

`<div class="product-menu" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">`

*After this change your example doesn't look perfect from a design point of view, some of the alignments are off, but I think this is your immediate blocker.*

---

If you're interested, I highly recommend these resources for learning about CSS flexbox:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://flexboxfroggy.com